# Complex Integration using Cauchy's Theorem: what do I set my $f(z)$ to?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I think that I have to use Cauchy's integration formula but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it in this case.

$$\int\frac{e^z+\sin z}{z^5}dz,$$

integrated along the path $r:[0,1]\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ where $r(t) = 3 + e^{2\pi i t}$.

Comment: Hint: the integrand is holomorphic inside the contour.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cauchy's theorem.  Since the integrand is analytic within the circle, the integral is zero.

Comment: How do you prove that the integrand is holomorphic in the circle?

Comment: The derivative exists everywhere except at $0$.